# How to access or pass props to child slot in vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

If you have this component hierarchy, is it possible to pass or access `isPanelClickable` from `ComponentPanel` in `ComponentSomething`?

```html
<ComponentA>
  <ComponentPanel :isPanelClickable="false">
    <ComponentSomething />
  </ComponentPanel>
</ComponentA>
```

*ComponentPanel:*

```html
<template>
  <div class="panel">
    <slot /> <!-- Can I "use" 'isPanelClickable' here somehow..? -->
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible through [scoped slots](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Scoped-Slots). `ComponentPanel` could pass a prop to the default slot by binding the prop (e.g., named `myProp`) on the corresponding `<slot>` element:

```html
<template>
  <slot :myProp="isPanelClickable ? 'I am clickable' : 'I do nothing'" />
</template>
```

That prop is then passed through the [`v-slot`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-slot) in the default slot:

```html
<ComponentPanel>
  <template v-slot="{ myProp }">
    <ComponentSomething :foo="myProp" />
  </template>
</ComponentPanel>
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/using-scoped-slots-in-vue-2-forked-uv95r?file=/src/App.vue)